# how to apply ease-out transition in Visual Studio Code text editor decoration

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How do I apply an ease-out transition to a `TextEditorDecorationType` in the Visual Studio Code API?

```
var flashDecorationType = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(100,200,100,0.5)'
});

var range = getCurrentRange();
var decoration = { range: range }
activeEditor.setDecorations(flashDecorationType, [decoration]);
```

The code above applies the decoration, but it is static and I want the background color to fade away in 1 second. Is this possible to do in vscode?

I would love to be able to do something like this:

```
var flashDecorationType = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(100,200,100,0.5)',
  transition: 'backgroundColor 1s ease-out'
});
```